# Where does geth store data except for the AppData\Roaming\Ethereum folder?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

The AppData\Roaming\Ethereum folder on my computer weighs 5GB, but geth has reduced my disk space by a lot more than 5GB.

Where else does it store data?

Answer (score 0):

I have the

- `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Ethash` Data for the proof of work algorithm used by Ethereum (previous version has stored data at `AppData\Local\Ethash`).